# Why is my D string showing a C♯ on my tuner?

Tags: guitar, tuning

I was playing for a bit and didn't tune any string, but when I wanted to tune it in at the end of my session my tuner kept saying C♯ instead of D. How do I get my D string back to its original state?

Comment: Are you a beginner?  The is a bit confusing, there's not enough data to answer.  Why do you think the guitar was in tune in the first place?  To answer directly turn the tuning peg until the tuner reads D.  Some times the tuning can slip overall and go flat depending on the guitar.

Comment: It's advisable to tune the guitar you play *at the beginning* of a session, not at the end! Also, it's good to have other ways to check tuning - 5th fret against next string open, harmonics, just listening...

Comment: @Tim From my experience, it takes a long time for beginners to even notice when a guitar isn't tuned properly. It takes even longer to be able to tune it by ear. Sure, it's very desireable but it's also very hard.

Comment: @EricDuminil - it does really need to be one of the first  skills learned. Hard or not, it's essential. And relying on tuners - don't get me started.

Comment: @Tim. I get your point. My hearing was so bad I simply couldn't tune anything by ear. Having a tuner allowed me to hear a well-tuned guitar right from the start. And only after hearing a well tuned guitar for a few years could I begin to have a better hearing and start tuning my guitar by ear. If tuning by ear is the first skill to learn, I wouldn't have played guitar for a long time, or even at all. What's your method for people with helplessly bad hearing?

Comment: As the answer points out, it depends on what kind of tuner you're using too!

Comment: @Tim I'll get you started. What's wrong with relying on tuners? Not everyone is physically capable of tuning by ear.

Comment: @only_pro - if ears can't tell if it's in tune, how will the player be able to tell if what he's playing is in tune? I use tuners occasionally - like just before a gig in a situation which requires silence on stage, or when the whole band is just too loud, but a player should be able to re-tune on the fly. A lot of pros would and do. And isn't it catastrophic when the battery goes flat? Seen that a few times!

Comment: @Tim I've never had trouble noticing when I was _playing_ out of tune, because generally the strings weren't all out of tune by the same amount, and the discord was obvious. I still had to break out the tuner to figure out which way each string needed to go. You're right that it's a valuable skill, but you've clearly forgotten how hard it is to learn, and until you remember, you shouldn't be demanding that it be learned first.

Comment: Turn the tuning peg?

Comment: @Tim https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_deaf_people#Deaf_and_hard_of_hearing_musicians Seems like many manage to struggle along somehow... Actually guitar is easy, compared to the muscle memory necessary to produce consistent pitch on a non-fretted stringed instrument.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding a digital tuner](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/14558/understanding-a-digital-tuner)

Answer (score 63):

The tuner does not hear what pitch your string is supposed to be at but only what pitch it actually is.  If your string is more than a quartertone flat, it is closer to a C♯ than to a D.  So your tuner then displays what kind of C♯ it thinks your pitch is.  Presumably a somewhat high one (assuming you are not more than a semitone flat). So tune upwards.  At some point of time your tuner is going to switch from claiming "too high for a C♯" to "too low for a D".  Then go further until the tuner is satisfied with the pitch being D.

Comment: This is the correct answer. To add one thing: new strings will stretch the first few times you play them. This will cause the string to go flat a bit. If you are using a guitar with new strings it is normal for them to go flat. If you are using a guitar with old strings it is possible they are strung incorrectly. Of course there is also the possibility that your D was closer to a c# when you started.

Comment: Another twist: some tuners also have a ["guitar" mode](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/14560/20675) which doesn't always display the actual pitch.  I don't know what that's about, except that I tried once to use one of dad's tuners, set to guitar mode, on my banjo and the results were nonsensical to me until I figured out to put the tuner in "chromatic" mode.

Comment: This answer is right, but I would generally advise caution for beginners when tuning strings up. Only do it when you're sure the string is actually too low. If it shows C♯ it almost certainly _is_ too low, but sometimes a tuner may show garbage when the string is already a lot _too high_. In doubt, one should always compare with an absolute reference (other guitar, perhaps “guitar tuning reference” video on the internet).

Comment: In addition to this answer I would recommend OP goes on YouTube and looks up tutorial videos, because there might be some wrong assumptions in the premise of the question.

Comment: @ Wayne Conrad - I suspect that *guitar mode* is specially designed to detect the precise pitches of a standard-tuned guitar. If your banjo plays the right note but the wrong octave it will confuse a guitar-only tuner.  (or if your string is supposed to be tuned to C on the banjo, a guitar-tuner will try to send you towards the nearest guitar pitch which is a D). I believe you can also get a specialist bass-guitar tuner. The advantage presumably is to stop you going towards the wrong octave which is easy for a beginner to do.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK you are correct -- "Guitar mode" tuners only indicate whether you're close to the standard 6 pitches.

Comment: I had a student arrive for a lesson, having 'tuned up' his guitar - with a tuner. The bottom E was in tune, but an octave too high. No, I couldn't believe it either, but it's true. One little reason I recommend trying other tuning methods as well. And if a learner can't tell if the guitar's in tune, how's he going to know if what he's playing is in tune...?

Comment: @Tim - I'm surprised the bridge didn't fly off and cause serious injury! What type of guitar was it?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - it was a stratalike, and survived to tell the tale.

Comment: @Tim - I've tuned the low E up an octave a few times through the years. Never had that string snap, but I've always realized my mistake when the A string explodes. :)

Comment: The tuner will not be going to switch from claiming "too high for a C♯" to "too low for a D". It is already claiming it is too low for a D, and hence indicates a C♯. I have never tuned an instrument but as I understand it, if  you tune upwards the tuner is going to switch from "claiming it is a (high) C♯" to "claiming it is a (low) D" at some point.

Comment: @Anthon Electronic tuners probably don't use words. It probably shows the text "C#", perhaps a colour indicating it's lower/higher than the note, and a rotating needle or something similar showing how much high/low it is. So I don't think you can really say whether it's saying *"too high for a C#"* or *"it is a high C#"*.

Answer (score 5):

Either:

*The tuner is buggered*: get a new tuner.

Or:

*The string is too loose*: tighten the string.

Answer (score 1):

I have had tuners seem like they were out of whack. But then I realized it wasn't set for Standard Tuning. Some tuners allow you to set it to Standard Tuning or Chromatic Tuning. If it is set to Chromatic Tuning you will see those sharp notes like that come up. As the one person mentioned, if you see a C# then keep tuning up until it changes to D. Then keep tuning up until it shows you are tuned to D. You should check the settings of the tuner as well. If it's set to Chromatic and you have an option to change it, you can change it to Standard Tuning or Guitar. One of my tuners has a choice of Chromatic, Guitar or a Bass setting. Anyway once you are off Chromatic Tuning, and in Standard Tuning, the tuner will stop displaying the sharp notes, and will go to the EADGBE, notes as you tune to them.